# How to build a single component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular app. I have completed my work and want to put the app onto the test server. But the requirement is that I just want to build a single component and put it onto the server.

I have tried `ng build` but it gives me the build of the whole app. But I want the build of just a single component.

I have looked onto the internet but nothing relevant could be found.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You wanna have a single component bundled? If so, then just create a new app with one component, use `ng build` and thats it. `ng build` bundles the whole app

Comment: The only way to do this is to develop the relevant component as a library. 
https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries
You can check out that repository: https://github.com/trungk18/angular-spotify

Answer (score 0):

ng generate component my-component-name

This is all described in the first pages of their tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0

Answer (score 0):

Use generate command to generate your component:

```
ng g c componentName
```

> https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command